# Call a parent method before(or after) any child method

Tags: c#, inheritance

Most likely I'll get negative answer here, but I'd like to ask my question.

Is there a way in C# to call the parent method before (or after) ANY child class method.

```
public class Base
{
    protected static void ThisWillBeCalledBeforeAnyMethodInChild()
    {
        //do something, e.g. log
    }

    protected static void ThisWillBeCalledAFTERAnyMethodInChild()
    {
        //do something, e.g. log
    }
}

public class SomeClass : Base
{
    public static void SomeMethod1()
    {
        //Do something
    }

    public static void SomeMethod2()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

So, I want to method `ThisWillBeCalledBeforeAnyMethodInChild` from Base class to run before `SomeMethod1` or `SomeMethod2` in `SomeClass`. Similar with after method.

Is there any way to do it without calling methods with reflection?

Comment: Here's the answer you were expecting: No. Not without rewriting the code at compile-time, or generating proxy types at runtime (for instance methods).

Comment: static would be hard to do that.

Answer (score 4):

So, aside from in your child method calling base.MethodNameYouWantToCall() before or after, you could take a different approach.

This is just an idea, and might not be what you're trying to achieve, but if I needed every child class to call parent functions before and after something I might do this:

```
class Parent 
{ 
   protected void Before() { /* does things */ }
   protected void After() { /* does things */ }
   abstract void OtherCode();

   public void PubliclyExposedMethod {
        Before();
        OtherCode();
        After();'
}
```

```
class Child : Parent {
      OtherCode { Console.Write("Hello world"); }
}
```

In the above, the method you define in the child will be *ran* after the before method, and before the after. I think this is cleaner because it reduces the number of times you need to write base.()

Comment: I've seen this a lot, where `OtherCode()` is called `PubliclyExposedMethodCore()` and is `abstract` or `protected virtual`.

Comment: The common name for this pattern is "template method", in case you want to read up on it more. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: `before` and `after` doesn't need to be `protected`, only `OtherCode` needs to be `protected`. Other then that, good answer.

Answer (score 1):

One idea that strikes my mind would be to write a wrapper method which gets an action as parameter. There you can call your before and after methods:

```
public class SomeClass : Base
{
    public static void SomeMethod1()
    {
        //Do something
    }

    public static void SomeMethod2()
    {
        //Do something
    }

    public static void WrapperMethod(Action action)
    {
        Base.ThisWillBeCalledBeforeAnyMethodInChild();
        action();
        Base.ThisWillBeCalledAFTERAnyMethodInChild
    }

}
```

You would call it this way:

```
SomeClass.WrapperMethod(()=> SomeClass.SomeMethod1());
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, static methods don't participate in inheritance.

You have total control over this by using the base pointer, which is a reference to the base class of the this pointer.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new SOmeClass();

        s.SomeMethod1();
        s.SomeMethod2();
    }
}

public class Base
{
    protected  void ThisWillBeCalledBeforeAnyMethodInChild()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ThisBefore");
    }

    protected  void ThisWillBeCalledAFTERAnyMethodInChild()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ThisAFTER");
    }
}

public class SOmeClass : Base
{
    public  void SomeMethod1()
    {
        base.ThisWillBeCalledBeforeAnyMethodInChild();
        Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod1");
    }

    public  void SomeMethod2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod2");
        base.ThisWillBeCalledAFTERAnyMethodInChild();
    }
}
```

Output:

ThisBefore
SomeMethod1
SomeMethod2
ThisAFTER

Comment: "First of all, static methods don't participate in inheritance." How did you arrive at this conclusion? change the `protected` in the `Base` class to `public` and you can see that now you can access and call `SomeClass.ThisWillBeCalledBeforeAnyMethodInChild`

Comment: That's not inheritance. That's just access.

Comment: static members are inherited, but can't be overriden. same as events.